# Questions about Spellcasting for Sorcerer

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-creation

First of all, I want to ask about what spells I know at what levels. At level 1, I know two level one spells (right?). At level two, I know three spells. Now, does that mean I know the two level one spells plus three level two spells or three spells total but I can learn one level 2 spell? Also, for “spell slots for spell level” I’m really confused. Can someone pleas explain these and where they go on the character sheet? My class is sorcerer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to rpg stack exchange. Your post has just been put on hold, but please do not be discouraged. :-) This forum's format does not suit the way you are asking your questions; you should try to split your post into separate questions. Moreover your post might get negative votes if you have not done a little bit of research yourself (like reading the Player's Handbook). Then please edit your question to make it clear which part of the text is confusing you.

Answer (score 6):

The *Spellcasting* class feature for your class gives you all the details of how you learn your spells. For the sorcerer, you want to pay specific attention to this sub-section ([which is on page 101 in the *Player's Handbook* and in the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#ClassFeatures)):

> **Spells Known of 1st Level and Higher**
>
> You know two 1st-level spells of your choice from the sorcerer spell list.
>
> The Spells Known column of the Sorcerer table shows when you learn more sorcerer spells of your choice. Each of these spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots. For instance, when you reach 3rd level in this class, you can learn one new spell of 1st or 2nd level.
>
> Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the sorcerer spells you know and replace it with another spell from the sorcerer spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

If it doesn't make it clear, the number of spells known on the Sorcerer table is your total number of known spells. So at Sorcerer level 2, you will know three different spells, since there's a three on the table. But they must all be 1st level spells, since you don't have any 2nd level spell slots yet (your number of slots are also shown on the table).

Whenever you level up, you can learn a new spell if your number of known spells has increased. That happens at every level early on (it slows down at higher levels). Regardless of whether you got any additional spells, you can always swap out one of your known spells for a new spell if you want to. All your spells must have levels that you have spell slots for. So you can replace a lower level spell with a higher level one, once you've leveled up enough to have access to the higher level slots.

As a level 3 Sorcerer, for example, you'll get your first 2nd level spell slots. You'll know four spells, of which up to two could be 2nd level (one completely new one and one you swapped out one of your 1st level spells for).

*P.S. Don't feel discouraged if you get confused by all the different meanings of the word "level". This is pretty widely recognized as one of D&D 5e's greatest misfeatures, as it makes explanations like this one very confusing for new players. The multiple meanings are mostly a legacy of older editions, carried forwards because they're traditional. You'll eventually figure it all out, just have patience.*

Comment: To clarify, I put all of my level spells corresponding with their spell level area, right? So like all the level 2 spells in the level 2 spot?

Comment: @NeonKraken As a 1st level sorcerer, you would only have cantrips and 1st level spells.  Note that "spell level" and "sorcerer  level" are different.

Comment: So just one more question, at level 5, I would know 6 spells. I have 4 1st level slots, 3 2nd level slots, and 2 3rd level spots. So obliviously this adds up to more than 6, do I just pick and choose between levels and replace lower level spells with higher level spells?

Comment: @NeonKraken: Your spells known don't need to closely match your numbers of spell slots. You can cast any spell with any spell slot of its level or higher. And you can cast a spell as many times as want to, as long as you have spell slots to spend on it. So if you wanted, at 5th level you could cast the same first level spell 9 times (ignoring sorcery points). But casting a higher-level spell is likely to be more powerful than casting a lower-level spell with a higher level slot, even if the lower-level spell improves with higher slot levels. And you probably want some variety anyway!

Comment: Oh I'm just talking about spells that I can actually know which I am writing down on my character sheet. From my knowledge, you can cast one spell/cantrip per turn unless it is a bonus action, correct? Are there any other limitations I should know about?

Comment: This site isn't really a good place to ask somebody to walk you through the rules like this. You should probably read the rules yourself (I linked and quoted the rules for learning new spells above), and talk to your DM if you're confused by them.

Comment: Ok I understand, sorry.